# meaning of a phrasal verb

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

The passage is from IT by Stephen King.

> They ran down Center Street. People turned to look at them. Ben’s
>   large stomach pogoed up and down. Beverly’s pony-tail bounced. Richie
>   let go of Ben and held his glasses against his forehead with his left
>   thumb so he wouldn’t lose them. ... They ***cut up*** Court Street and
>   collapsed on a bench in front of the police station: at that moment it
>   seemed the only place in Derry where they might possibly be safe.

I want to ask the meaning of the bold-faced ***cut up***. 
The several dictionaries I looked up didn’t give any meanings to fit this context.
It seems like they (Beverly, Richie, and Ben) sharply turned their direction of fleeing to Court Street.

Am I right?

Comment: *They took [**a short cut**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/short-cut) [by going **up** Court Street]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cut definition 6. *Up* is used rather than *across* because they ran *up* Court Street as a shortcut.